# Symbols in Where conditions mysql php

Tags: mysql

I've a string in mysql database like "® Windows Vista™ Business" (with symbols) in column name "os".

I try to run query "SELECT * FROM `DeviceRegistration` WHERE `os`='$OS'"

it not work.. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Because you are comparing small string with complete string **® Windows Vista™ Business**

Comment: You should try something like **SELECT * FROM DeviceRegistration  WHERE os='® Windows Vista™ Business'**

Comment: What is the table/database collation?  Are you using PHP?

Comment: I allready try **SELECT * FROM DeviceRegistration WHERE os='® Windows Vista™ Business'** but it not work for me

Comment: Check here http://rextester.com/LCFB32220

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `mysqli_real_escape($string)`when you use php.  Otherwise you could use a ‚where like‘ Query if your string doesnt fit the database entry 100%.